# UITableView header constraints fails only on iOS 8 when table is not empty

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

That is so strange. I am using very simple header, just one label inside  whole view.I have fallowing error:

```
 (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf33680 H:|-(15)-[UILabel:0x7bff5530'TITLE\nDESCRIPTION']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bfdac80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf63c40 H:[UILabel:0x7bff5530'TITLE\nDESCRIPTION']-(15)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bfdac80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf1a870 H:[UIView:0x7bfdac80]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':ATableViewInfoHeaderView:0x7bfccf10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf29370 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7bfdac80]   (Names: '|':ATableViewInfoHeaderView:0x7bfccf10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d180970 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[ATableViewInfoHeaderView:0x7bfccf10(0)]>"
 )

 Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
 <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf63c40 H:[UILabel:0x7bff5530'TITLE
 DESCRIPTION']-(15)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bfdac80 )>
```

But it happens only when:

a) I am using on ios 8 (ios 7 works great).
b) The table is not empty!
c) I am using UITableViewCell without custom xib file in table view.

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: make sure you don't set frame with zero height to header view. OR just reduce label's Top and Bottom constraints priority to Hight(750) or even lower.

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk it is not about bottom and top it is about width. Setting priority of the constraint (15) to 750 solve problem. But this is a workaround. What is a reason?

Comment: I suppose your tableView's frame is equal CGRectZero when you assign tableHeaderView or become zero after that for some time

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk I have just changed constraint from = 15 to <= 15. So your ideal could be true. Somehow section header changes its size to zero during refreshing.